# Constructor , new keyword

Tags: java

```
class Student {
  int id;
  String name;

  Student() {
    System.out.println("default");
  }

  Student(int id, String name) {
    this();

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  Void display() {
    System.out.println(id + "" + name);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Student e1 = new Student(111, "karan");
    e1.display();
  }
}
```

The Output am getting is :

```
default
111 karan.
```

I don't understand why am getting default in output , i called the constructer that have arguments

Comment: You should post better formatted code if you want help - the more effort you put into your questions the more people will be able and willing to help (just for future reference). Besides that you'r parameter constructor is calling the no-arg constructor (`this();`).

Comment: If you'd step through your code using the debugger, you'd find out yourself.

Comment: what do you think `this();` is doing in the constructor? why do you have it there?

Answer (score 2):

in your constructor with arguments:

```
 Student(int id, String name){
   this();

   this.id=id;
   this.name=name;
 }
```

in the first line you are invoking a this();

That is calling the constructor whitout arguments.

```
 Student(){
   System.out.println("default");
 }
```

So the result is:

```
default
111karan
```

Normally you don't invoke the other constructor, so remove the this(); in the constructor with arguments resulting

```
Student(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

So you will have

```
111karan
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting "default" in the output because you are calling this(); in the parameterized constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling

```
this()
```

in the second constructor (the one with arguments). This means the first constructor is called, so it prints "default". It then goes on like normal. Try either commenting out (In case you're likely to need it later), or deleting the first line in the second constructor. It should be:

```
Student(int id, String name){
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
}
```

Edit: I'm assuming that when you say it prints out "default 111 karan", you don't mean that it's all on the same line in the console. If so, something weird's gone wrong with your System.out.println().

Comment: It prints default because when you call a constructor that takes arguement, the first thing that it does is calls the no-arg constructor before executing any of the lines of the actual parameterized constructor that is called. There is an implicit this() placed on the very first line of the parameterized constructor by the jvm. Hence at first it prints default even if you do not explicitly call the default constructor.

Comment: `this()` is *not* implicitly called by every constructor. Every constructor must explicitly call another constructor, otherwise `super()` will be called implicitly. (If `super()` doesn't exist or is inaccessible, it's a compile-time error.) Maybe that's what your confused about? But it's not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Student(int id, String name){
    this(); // You are calling the constructor with no arguments

    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.